# find and replace strings in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var add_to_list = $(this);
    // database query for element
});
```

Currently `add_to_list` is getting the value `'images/image.jpg'`. I want to replace the `'image/'` to nothing so I only get the name of the picture (with or without the extension). How can I do this? I couldn't find anything. Also please provide me with further reading on string manipulation please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [javascript replace function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) ?

You should modify your code to something like this:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var add_to_list = $(this).attr('src').replace('images/', '');  
    // database query for element
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
add_to_list.substring(7);
```

This will get you the string after the 7th character.  If there might be longer paths, you can `split()` into an array and get the last part of the path using `pop()`.

```
add_to_list.split("/").pop();
```

- [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Substring)
- [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/split)
- [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/pop)

[This tutorial](http://richardbowles.tripod.com/javascript/section10/lesson10.htm) explains many of the string manipulation methods seen in the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var add_to_list = $(this).attr('src').replace('image/', '');
    // database query for element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pieces = add_to_list.split('/');
var filename = pieces[pieces.length-1];
```